# Different jsse.enableSNIExtension system property in a web project

Tags: java

I'm talking about web project so its war file

I set the System property with

```
System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension","false"/"true");
```

and then execute

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
```

only the first invocation reads the property and on the second invocation the property is changed but httpClient is executes with the value from the property of the first invocation.

how to make it work?

Comment: You can't change this global setting for individual connections. The property is read once, and the value is cached, so it has to be set to the desired value before any SSL context is created. In Java 8, there is a plug-in API to control this case-by-case, which requires some extra code.

Comment: 1. do I understand right ? execute method creates some instance whose class has  static block in which SNI property is read ?
2. Why its made that way?

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly. System properties are global; there's no way to scope them, so they could be read by any thread at any time. In that sense, it doesn't make sense to change them, because different threads changing the values at the same time without coordination could break things. Programs should only read system properties, not set them. If they do set them, it should be only once, during initialization of the whole process (like in a main method).

Comment: Some properties can be changed multiple times. javax.net.ssl.trustStore for example can be changed whenever we want and the newly set TrustStore path will be used. So may be the conclusion is : It depends how the object is implemented.